# Flitering list that may content null or empty string

Tags: flutter, dart

I am filtering a list as follows:

```
return Container(
                      child: FutureBuilder(
                        future: fetchCremas(),
                        builder: (context, snapshot) {
                          if (snapshot.hasData) {
                            var filteredList = snapshot.data;
                            filteredList = filteredList
                                .where((element) => (element.nombre
                                .toLowerCase()
                                .contains(
                                _controller.text.toLowerCase())
                                || element.descripcion.toLowerCase().contains(
                                    _controller.text.toLowerCase())
                                || element.sub_cat_nombre.toLowerCase().contains(
                                    _controller.text.toLowerCase())
                                || element.sub_cat2_nombre.toLowerCase().contains(
                                    _controller.text.toLowerCase())
                                || element.sub_cat3_nombre.toLowerCase().contains(
                                    _controller.text.toLowerCase())
                            ))
                                .toList();
```

The issue is that element.sub_cat3_nombre may be empty or null.

Using this code I am getting an error

```
The method 'toLowerCase' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: toLowerCase()
```

How can I keep filtering on element.sub_cat3_nombre taking into account that it may be empty or null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**some value is Nullable String not String**

handled it from backend return String without Nullable ,
to avoid extra cast or check-null

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
element.sub_cat3_nombre?.toLowerCase()
```

Comment: I am using a previous version of Flutter, it is not Null Safety, I guess I should find another way to get it work

Comment: I am using a previuos version of Flutter in a project too and the operator `?` works for checking if a variable is null before call an attribute.

Comment: To clarify: `?.` existed long before null safety.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this?

```
filteredList.where((element) => (element.nombre?.toLowerCase() ?? here put replacement object
```

or you could use `if(element.nombre != null)` before you start filtering